# Alternative SQL queries

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, having

I need three alternative queries return Identical answer as This query below.

```
SELECT building, SUM(budget) AS totalbudget
FROM department 
GROUP BY building
HAVING SUM(budget) > 10000;
```

Create three alternative ways to get the same exact result eliminating the `HAVING` clause. And for each alternative explain the impact of the query on performance?

First way:

```
SELECT building, totalbudget
FROM 
    (SELECT building, SUM(budget) AS totalbudget
     FROM department 
     GROUP BY building)
WHERE totalbudget > 10000;
```

There are still two other ways...

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products have different optimization tricks.)

Comment: I mean,I ask for different queries for that query in question  without having clause. I use ORACLE

Comment: Yes, but you also wrote "_for each alternative explain the impact of the query on performance_".

Comment: **YOU** ask? Do you mean to say that this is not a homework or interview question?

Comment: Actually it's an exam question. is that not allowed ??. but it is a good question.

Comment: It is allowed, but then don't say "**I**" ask. Be honest and say **they** ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   department
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY building
  MEASURES
    SUM(budget) AS totalBudget
  PATTERN (^ all_rows+ $)
  DEFINE
    all_rows AS 1 = 1
)
WHERE totalBudget > 10000
```

#### Option 2:

```sql
SELECT building,
       SUM(budget) AS totalbudget
FROM   department d
WHERE  10000 < (
  SELECT SUM(budget)
  FROM   department t
  WHERE  d.building = t.building
)
GROUP BY building
```

#### Option 3:

```sql
SELECT building,
       SUM(budget) AS totalbudget
FROM   department
GROUP BY building
ORDER BY totalbudget DESC
FETCH FIRST ( SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM   (
                SELECT SUM(budget) AS total
                FROM   department
                GROUP BY building
              )
              WHERE total > 10000            ) ROWS ONLY;
```

> And for each alternative explain the impact of the query on performance?

They'll all have worse performance than using `HAVING`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7c3d63681447baea5ef030be6b3eeca6)*